# Show multiple pages for large screen sizes in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building a simple app with a side menu and two ion-tab. What I am trying to do is, when the screen wide enough, forget about the tabs and open both pages side by side:

[image: Large screens layout]

To keep the menu visible if the screen is large enough, I am using:

`<ion-split-pane when="lg">`

And to hide the Tabs:

TS file: `this.showTabs = platform.width() < 992;`

And then, in the HTML file, I just add the attribute: `*ngIf="showTabs"`

Is it possible to load two pages inside an ion-content? Any alternative solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: yeah, just use the selector of the pages. `<page1></page1>` and `<page2></page2` and find some css to align them next to eachother instead of under eachother

Comment: Hi Ivaro18, could you write a simple example of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution for this. I'll post it here in case someone experiences the same problem.

We can create a custom component with:

```
ionic generate component name-of-component
```

The components can be embedded within the ionic pages. To use them in a Page, you just have to import the component in the *.module.ts* of the Page and then use the HTML tag with the selector name of the component, as Ivaro18 mentioned:

```
<component-name></component-name>
```

If you want to use lazy loading, you can create a *components.module.ts* inside the *components* folder to act as an index of all the custom components. It would look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Component1 } from './component1/component1';
import { Component2 } from './component2/component2';
import { Component3 } from './component3/component3';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        Component1,
        Component2,
        Component3
    ],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [
        Component1,
        Component2,
        Component3
    ]
})

export class ComponentsModule{}
```

Then, in the Pages, we would import ComponentsModule. That would allow us to lazy load any of the components:

```
<component-2-selector></component-2-selector>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: do you have any example of this?